# Excel: Is it possible to change a form color fill based on a value?

Tags: excel, dashboard

I'm trying to change a form fill from my project summary based on its completion.
it should look like this

[image]

1. If not all itens are "OK"
2. Form on the left is blue

If there is nothing to verify or correct it should be like this

[image]

I've been searching for a solution but couldn't find any, can you give a hand on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make the bar depend on a simple [boolean formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) like this one:

```
=IF(OR(B2>0;B1>0);100;0)
=100-B7
```

[image]

Thus, if there is something in "Verify" or in "Bugs" it will be blue and if it is "0", it will be red (colors can be edited later):

[image]

Comment: Excel doesnt allow me to associate this formula with the form
The given error is:
"This formula does not contain a refered interval or defined name"
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @VictorYOO - associate the form with the cell, in which the formula is written. In my case, this is `B7:B8`.

Comment: Ooh, got it! Now the given result is "#Name?"

Comment: @VictorYOO - make sure that there are some numbers in the range. Try to replicate the sample case 100% and then adjust it to your data.

Comment: The numbers in range are based on a countif from other tabs, is there a way this formula links to countif?

Comment: Yeah. Make it a conditional boolean formula, that returns "0" if the result from `countif()` is "0" and "100" if the result from `countif()` is above "0". But in general, try to replicate the sample case 100% and then adjust it to your data.

Comment: I was using my native language for formulas not english, sorry for the confusion
Can you help me with one more thing? How do i set colors based on given result? Conditional formatting is not working, its returning 0 or 100 in the side bar

Comment: @VictorYOO - just a play a bit with the settings or go to google and google this `how do i set colors based on given result excel chart -conditional -formatting`